# The expression $\sqrt{13+3\sqrt{\frac{23}{3}}} +\sqrt{13-3\sqrt{\frac{23}{3}}} $ is which type of number?

Tags: complex-numbers

> (a) A natural number,
>
> (b) A rational number but not a natural number,
>
> (c) An irrational number not exceeding 6,
>
> (d) An irrational number
> exceeding 6.

Please help with this, i can't manage to simplify it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user35508 Why irrational?

Comment: Because $x^2$ is not the square of a rational number.

Comment: Use the double radicals formula to simplify and the it will be apparent that you have an irrational *exceeding* 6.

Comment: Silly question, but how do we know that square root of $226$ will not be a rational number?

Comment: @RobertIsrael You are right, my arithmetic was off. To the OP: let $a=\sqrt{13+3\sqrt{\frac{23}{3}}}$ and $b= \sqrt{13-3\sqrt{\frac{23}{3}}}\,$. Then $a^2+b^2=26$ and $ab=10$, so $a+b = \sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab}=\sqrt{46}$.

Comment: For your comment on 226, it lies between the two perfect squares 225 (15 squared) and 256 (16 squared) and so is not a perfect square itself and hence $\sqrt{226}$ isn't rational.

Comment: Got it! Many thanks..

Comment: Sorry Idkwoman but please change your profile picture its very disturbing.

Comment: Sorry for your trouble, but that's how my face looks when i'm able to solve  a math problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us assume 
$$\sqrt{13+3\sqrt{\frac{23}{3}}} +\sqrt{13-3\sqrt{\frac{23}{3}}}=x $$
Squaring and simplifying  gives 
 $$26+20=x^2$$
which gives $$x=+\sqrt{46}$$

Since $6=
\sqrt{36}<\sqrt{46}<\sqrt{49}=7$

The result is $(D)$